# How does bodyparser and multer work together in Express?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, multer, body-parser

Let's suppose I send a file that contains both string fields and a file image attached. This is how I do it in the front-end:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('title', postData.title);
formData.append('content', postData.content);
formData.append('image', postData.image);
```

And this is my middleware configuration in Express:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
    multer({ storage: fileStorage, fileFilter }).single('image')
);
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
    next();
});
```

So, who exactly is parsing the string fields? If I attached a JSON object to FormData, how would bodyparser.json() know where to find the JSON data and what to ignore because it is a file?